# Unexpected StandardScaler fit_transform output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to scale a pandas Series with StandardScaler().fit_transform().  However, the output is always an array of zeros.

The input Series has a length of 201, when I do:

```
print values[:5]
```

I get a list of floats as below:

```
0    1943.0
1     508.0
2    1657.0
3     872.0
4     693.0
```

When I apply the scaler:

```
X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(values)
print X
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a pd.Series? check with `type(values)` this tends to happen if you have a dataframe with several columns.

Comment: I'm sure it's a Series (I constructed it as pd.Series(data=lst) ).  It's a series with features of one sample though, is it possible to scale a single sample with StandardScaler?     I managed to fix the issue by using preprocessing.scale(values, axis=1) instead

Comment: can you make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample data? I tried your code and it works ok for me.

Comment: `import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
    
inputs = pd.DataFrame()
lst =  range(5)
inpt = pd.Series(data=lst)
values = inputs.append(inpt, ignore_index=True)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(values)
print X`

Comment: In your example `values` is a DataFrame while you mention that you are sure that your data is a pd.Series. You can check what you pass to the scaler with `type(values)`.

Comment: if you use a pd.Series, for example `inpt = pd.Series(range(5));scaler.fit_transform(inpt.reshape(-1, 1))` then it works as it should.